# Selectively Uninstalling Windows Updates

Tags: windows-xp, windows-update, uninstall

I recently installed a bunch of updates from the Windows update site.  Now, some of the previously installed enterprise Java applications on my computer are not functioning properly, so I would like to back out these updates.  Ideally, System Restore would do the trick, but the IT admins here disabled that feature.  From `Control Panel -> Add/Remove Programs` I can select any single update and remove it without issue.  Unfortunately, it doesn't give you a nice sortable list (i.e. install dates are often missing and you can't sort by KB#).  I already uninstalled the handful of updates that I could find without fixing the problem.  Is there another way (command line or another tool or utility) that I can use to selectively uninstall Windows updates?  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NirSoft WinUpdateList does the trick.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/wul.html