# How can I uninstall a specific Windows 7 update?

Tags: windows-7, windows-update, uninstall, .net-framework

My Windows 7 has automatically installed a bunch of updates that make no sense - e.g. `Security Update for Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5.1 on Windows 7 SP1 and Windows Server 2008 R2 SP1 for x64 (KB3072305)` when I have .NET Framework 4.6.1. All the answers I've found on SU so far failed to work.

The update does *not* show up in Control Panel -> Programs and Features -> Installed Updates. Searching for the KB number there finds nothing.

`wusa /uninstall /kb:3072305` fails with

> Installer encountered an error: 0x800b0100
>
> No signature was present in the subject.

[Nirsoft's wul](https://superuser.com/questions/385643/selectively-uninstalling-windows-updates) has the "uninstall" option greyed out for any update I've checked, including this one.

[image: Nirsoft Windows Update List fail]

Comment: You can only uninstall an update if you have not used system cleanup to remove the data required to do so.  Which means your options are limited to, download the executable that would install it, then choosing to uninstall it.

Comment: You probably DO have .Net 3.5.1 installed.  It's a Windows "Feature" in 7, and therefor doesn't show up in the Add/Remove Programs list. Instead look under "Turn Windows features on or off" and see if it's enabled.  "All the answers I've found on SU so far failed to work." Since we're unable to read your mind, nor have we memorized every question/answer on SU, please edit your question to include what you actually tried, and what the results were.

Comment: You can have `.NET Framework 3.5.1` installed and `NET Framework 4.6.1`  without causing a problem so why do you want to uninstall an security update?

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007: I had linked to the Nirsoft answer and summarized in the question the gist of [the others](http://superuser.com/search?q=uninstall+windows+update).